# Write a recursive method to compare two strings?

Tags: java, sorting, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Recursion To Compare Strings To Determine Which Comes First Alphabetically Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726821/using-recursion-to-compare-strings-to-determine-which-comes-first-alphabetically)

I'm stuck on this recursion problem to alphabetically sort any two strings. Here's the method signature:

```
int compareTo(String s1, String s2)
```

it yeilds:

`returnval <0` means `s1 < s2`

`returnval ==0` means    `s1 == s2`

`returnval >0` means     `s1 > s2`

Here is the code I have:

```
package bonushw;

public class Recursion {

  public void main (String[] args){
      Recursion recurse = new Recursion();
      System.out.println("value is: " + recurse.compareTo("bill","bill"));
    }  

  public int compareTo (String s1, String s2) {

    if(s1.length() == 0){
      return 0;
    }
    else if (s1.charAt(0) < s2.charAt(0)){
      return -1;
    }
    else if (s1.charAt(0) > s2.charAt(0)) {
      return 1;
    }
    else {
      return compareTo(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1));
    }
  }
```

thanks

Comment: @AmitBhargava - I just added  my code, thanks

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?  What is wrong with it?

Comment: What should the value of `compareTo("","Hello World")` be?

Comment: @LouisWasserman - it looks fine to you?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public static void main(String[] args)` (Missing `static`)

Comment: I think compareTo ( "HelloWorld" , "" ) is going to blow up.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson technically yes, but that duplicate is terrible.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(s1.length() == 0){
      return 0;
    }
```

This is incomplete, what if both are empty, what if s2 is empty?

Comment: good point AKJ, yes OP needs to thoroughly check that

Comment: ok i changed it to: ` (s1.length() == 0) || (s2.length() == 0)`

Comment: @IkechukwuOkechukwuJr This is still incorrect. You should have a condition like this: if(s1.length()==0 && s2.length()==0) return 0; else if (s1.length()==0 && s2.length()>0) return -1; else if (s1.length()>0 && s2.length==0) return 1;

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class Compare
{
    public static int compareTo(String s1, String s2)
    {
        int len = s1.length() < s2.length() ? s1.length() : s2.length();

        if (len == 0 && s1.length() > 0)
            return -1;
        else if (len == 0 && s2.length() > 0)
            return 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            int v1 = s1.charAt(i);
            int v2 = s2.charAt(i);

            if (v1 == v2)
                return compareTo(s1.substring(1, s1.length()),
                                 s2.substring(1, s2.length()));
            else
                return v1 - v2;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(compareTo("", ""));        //  0
        System.out.println(compareTo("a", "a"));      //  0
        System.out.println(compareTo("ab", "a"));     // -1
        System.out.println(compareTo("a", "ab"));     //  1
        System.out.println(compareTo("abc", "abc"));  //  0
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, instead of `s1.substring(1, s1.length())` simply write `s1.substring(1)`. It is equivalent and much simpler to read.

Comment: Your for-loop is unecessary as it will exit after its first iteration with the `return` statement. Just use `s1.charAt(0)` and `s2.charAt(0)` and remove the for-loop.